# Unwanted zero in array

Tags: java, arrays

My method takes in three parameters. a is an array of integers, low is the low number in a range, and high is the high number. I'm trying to search through the array to find numbers in between the low and high, add them to another array, and return the new array.

The array that I'm returning always starts with zero even when zero isn't included in the initial array. For example, if a = {7, 9}, with the low being 5 and the high being 7, b is {0, 7, 9}. Can someone give me some advice on what I'm doing wrong.

```
public static int[] range(int[] a, int low, int high) {

  int[] b = new int[0];
  if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
     throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }
  else {
     for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        if (a[i] >= low && a[i] <= high) {
           b = Arrays.copyOf(b, 
              b.length + 1);
           b[b.length - 1] = a[i];
        }
     }
  }   
  return b;
}
```

This is the test that keeps failing

```
@Test public void Selector_range_1() {
  int[] a = {1, 9, 7, 5, 3};
  int low = 1;
  int high = 9;
  int[] e = {1, 9, 7, 5, 3};
  Assert.assertArrayEquals(e, Selector.range(a, low, high));
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly fine for me: `range(new int[] {7,9}, 5, 7)` returns `{7}`.

Comment: This works fine [demo](http://ideone.com/TgFn1u).

Comment: That code would be simpler, and run much faster, with `ArrayList`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the code. May be you should show us how are you calling this function, you might be making some mistake there, if you dont see expected output.

Comment: And now that you've added a test, it passes for me as well. Really not sure what the problem is for you.

Comment: Yeah, me either. I'm going to get someone to look into it. Thanks for everyones time, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything wrong with your code, when i run it i can not recreate your problem. I think you problem lies somewhere else in your code. Perhaps you save your result in an array with a 0 in it.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] a = {7,9};
    int[] b = range(a, 0,10);

    for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(b[i]);
    }


}

public static int[] range(int[] a, int low, int high) {

      int[] b = new int[0];
      if (a == null || a.length == 0) {
         throw new IllegalArgumentException();
      }
      else {
         for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            if (a[i] >= low && a[i] <= high) {
               b = Arrays.copyOf(b, 
                  b.length + 1);
               b[b.length - 1] = a[i];
            }
         }
      }   
      return b;
    }
```

Comment: I tried changing the name of the array, but I'm still having the same issue.

Comment: So if you, run my code you still get {0,7,9} ? It's hard for us to guess whats going on around your method, but the method does not seem to be the problem.

Comment: I tried setting up the same jUnit as you and it seems to pass.  [image of test passing](http://imgur.com/cI7JKUq),  I don't know why your test is failing.